# button onclick with get_post_permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, loop, permalinks, buttons

I developed a custom post type.
On my archive page for each post there is a `<button>`.
The problem is that I can't put the link to the post in question.
My button is in my loop.

`<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='<?php get_post_permalink();?>'"> Click here </button>`

Comment: Can I ask why you're using a button like this? A link to a post should be an `a` element. There's nothing about your code that requires a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_post_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_permalink/) only returns the value. You still need to echo it (and [escape it](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/) for good measure):

```
<?php echo esc_url( get_post_permalink() );?>
```

Comment: Cool thank you :)